# How do I stop PyCharm from autocompleting class methods?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

When I type:

`def method(`, PyCharm jumps in with `def method(self):`. I would like to disable this behaviour.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The option is located at:

*Settings > Editor > Smart Keys > Insert Self...*

**EDIT:** As of `pycharm 2017.1` it's under File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys

Comment: As mentioned in Robert Fey's answer, "Smart Keys" is now under "General", but it was easy enough to find with the built-in search

Answer (score 4):

Go to *File > Settings (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)  > [IDE Settings] > Editor > Code Completion*.

The "Autopopup code completion" setting will determine if the popup opens automatically. Below it, the "Insert selected variant by typing dot, space, etc." is likely the setting you want to turn off.

Answer (score 4):

In PyCharm 2017.1

File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys -> "Insert 'self' when defining a method"