# How to stop Pycharm from attempting to autocomplete when I type in a comment?

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm

PyCharm attempts to auto complete when I'm typing plain text inside a comment, which is incredibly annoying and makes me have to press Esc on pretty much every word to prevent variable names and other symbols to be inserted when I'm typing just regular English.

```
def method():
    """
    PLEASE do NOT auto complete here... this is just text.
    """
```

How can I make it stop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23432543/how-do-i-stop-pycharm-from-autocompleting-class-methods

Comment: No.. unfortunately that is a different setting.

Comment: @EdyBourne if you find a way to turn the functionality on please let me know, I've been trying to get it to work but haven't figured out how.